# Regex to find words and wrap quotes

Tags: regex

I am trying to find words with spaces that are surrounded by `(`, `)` or `,` and wrap them in quotes..

For e.g. In this expression - `Development life cycle` and `enterprise service bus` are to be wrapped in quotes.

Edit - Only phrases i.e. Words that contain spaces between them are to be wrapped

```
(AND(OR(SDLC,development life cycle),design,requirements,OR(biztalk,Websphere,TIBCO,Webmethods,ESB,enterprise service bus)))
```

Comment: That string contains lots of words: but you've highlighted only some of them. What distinguishes the cases to be quoted from the others? Also which regex engine are you using? (There are significant differences whichwill make a difference in this case: matching paired characters, like parentheses, is not part of regular languages so regexes need extensions to do it.)

Comment: Sorry about.. Just edited the question. Need to apply the regex only for phrases

Comment: "Phrase" can mean different things. Please define precisely. And we still do not know which regex engine you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=[(,])([^(),]* [^(),]*)(?=[),])
```

Try this. See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/64).

Replace by `"$1"` or `"\1"`

```
string strRegex = @"(?<=[(,])([^(),]* [^(),]*)(?=[),])";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"(AND(OR(SDLC,development life          cycle),design,requirements,OR(biztalk,Websphere,TIBCO,Webmethods,ESB,enterprise service bus)))" + "\n" + @" AND(OR(SDLC,""development life cycle""),OR(banking,AML,anti-money laundering,KYC,know your customer),OR(technology strategy,technical strategy,technical architecture,technology architecture,architect*)";
string strReplace = @"""$1""";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Comment: I am looking for a generic Regex that searches for phrases surrounded by ( ) or ,

Comment: Thanks ! It works for most test cases.. But fails for some..  For this guy technical architecture , anti-money laundering are not wrapped   

AND(OR(SDLC,"development life cycle"),OR(banking,AML,anti-money laundering,KYC,"know your customer"),OR(technology strategy,technical strategy,technical architecture,technology architecture,"architect*"))

Comment: @SandBox can you post the string whihc is not working in the question

Comment: The comment above has the string that is not working

Phrases like technical architecture , anti-money laundering, technical strategy

AND(OR(SDLC,"development life cycle"),OR(banking,AML,anti-money laundering,KYC,"know your customer"),OR(technology strategy,technical strategy,technical architecture,technology architecture,"architect*"))

Comment: Works perfectly - @vks . :)

Comment: I tried this regex "/(?<=[(,])([^(),]* [^(),]*)(?=[),])/gi" in C# but does not seem to work.. Ideas?

Comment: appreciate it.. another problem - The regex adds quotes even if space is not in the phrase                

for example : (AND(architect, eCommerce, TOGAF))

It adds quotes even the single words and gives me this : (AND(architect," eCommerce"," TOGAF"))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74656/discussion-between-sandbox-and-vks).